# Most efficient way to join two time series

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Imagine I have a table like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE time_series (
        snapshot_date DATE,
        sales INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (snapshot_date));
```

With values like this:

```
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-01'::DATE AS snapshot_date,10 AS sales;
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-02'::DATE AS snapshot_date,4 AS sales;
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-03'::DATE AS snapshot_date,13 AS sales;
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-04'::DATE AS snapshot_date,7 AS sales;
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-05'::DATE AS snapshot_date,15 AS sales;
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-06'::DATE AS snapshot_date,8 AS sales;
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
SELECT a.snapshot_date, 
       AVG(b.sales) AS sales_avg,
       COUNT(*) AS COUNT
  FROM time_series AS a
  JOIN time_series AS b
       ON a.snapshot_date > b.snapshot_date
 GROUP BY a.snapshot_date
```

Which produces results like this:

```
*---------------*-----------*-------*
| snapshot_date | sales_avg | count |
*---------------*-----------*-------*
|  2017-01-02   |   10.0    |    1  |
|  2017-01-03   |   7.0     |    2  |
|  2017-01-04   |   9.0     |    3  |
|  2017-01-05   |   8.5     |    4  |
|  2017-01-06   |   9.8     |    5  |
-------------------------------------
```

With a trivial number of rows, like in this example, the query runs super fast. Problem is I have to do this for millions of rows, and on Redshift (similar in syntax to Postgres) my query takes days to run. It's horribly slow, and yet this is one of my most common query patterns. I suspect that the problem is due to growth of O(n^2) in the data vs the more preferable O(n).

My O(n) implementation in python would be something like this:

```
rows = [('2017-01-01',10),
        ('2017-01-02',4),
        ('2017-01-03',13),
        ('2017-01-04',7),
        ('2017-01-05',15),
        ('2017-01-06',8)]
sales_total_previous = 0
count = 0
for index, row in enumerate(rows):
    snapshot_date = row[0]
    sales = row[1]
    if index == 0:
        sales_total_previous += sales
        continue
    count += 1
    sales_avg = sales_total_previous / count
    print((snapshot_date,sales_avg, count))
    sales_total_previous += sales
```

With results like this (same as SQL query):

```
('2017-01-02', 10.0, 1)
('2017-01-03', 7.0, 2)
('2017-01-04', 9.0, 3)
('2017-01-05', 8.5, 4)
('2017-01-06', 9.8, 5)
```

I'm considering switching to Apache Spark so that I can do exactly that python query, but several million rows is isn't really that large (it's at most 3-4 GB) and using a Spark cluster with 100 GB of RAM seems like overkill. Is there an efficient and easy-to-read way I can get O(n) efficiency in SQL, preferably in Postgres / Redshift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT ts.snapshot_date, 
       AVG(ts.sales) OVER (ORDER BY ts.snapshot_date) AS sales_avg,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts.snapshot_date) AS COUNT
FROM time_series ts;
```

You'll find that using window functions is much more efficient.

Comment: Wow. That is truly amazing. It brought my run-time down from a week to just 23 seconds.