# Window function on joined tables

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to use the efficiency of window functions similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103964/most-efficient-way-to-join-two-time-series). In the linked example I was able to use a window function so that I didn't have to join a table onto itself. The speed-up was dramatic -- roughly O(n^2) to O(n). In this question, there is no way around the join, and yet both my tables are extremely large (millions of rows) and I want to again avoid O(n^2) blowing up of the data. Will the window function, or something similar, still work in this case?

I have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE reports (
        report_date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (report_date));

CREATE TABLE time_series (
        snapshot_date DATE,
        sales INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (snapshot_date));
```

With values like this:

```
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-01'::DATE AS snapshot_date,10 AS sales;
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-02'::DATE AS snapshot_date,4 AS sales;
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-03'::DATE AS snapshot_date,13 AS sales;
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-04'::DATE AS snapshot_date,7 AS sales;
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-05'::DATE AS snapshot_date,15 AS sales;
INSERT INTO time_series SELECT '2017-01-06'::DATE AS snapshot_date,8 AS sales;

INSERT INTO reports SELECT '2017-01-03'::DATE AS report_date;
INSERT INTO reports SELECT '2017-01-06'::DATE AS report_date;
```

I'd like to perform a join like this (but more efficiently):

```
SELECT r.report_date,  
       SUM(sales) AS total_sales
  FROM reports AS r
  JOIN time_series AS ts
       ON r.report_date > ts.snapshot_date
 GROUP BY r.report_date
 ORDER BY r.report_date
```

And get results like this:

```
*---------------*-------------*
|  report_date  | total_sales |
*---------------*-------------*
|  2017-01-03   |     14      |
|  2017-01-06   |     49      |
------------------------------*
```

Comment: What's inefficient about what you already have? Given the current appearance of your data, an alternative could be to first generate a running balance of `sales` on `time_series`, and then do an equi-join onto `report_date`.

Comment: @Steve What's an equi-join? While I could do a running balance of `sales` on `time_series` I want to avoid multiplying `sales` proportionate to the number of rows in `reports`. If I select the top ranked / most recent running balance of `sales` doesn't that still require sorting through all of the running balance of sales for each record in `reports`? The appeal of the window function is that it appears to go through the running balances only once as opposed to repeatedly for each row in `reports`

Answer (score 1):

@user554481, from the comments.

As you say, the window function is likely to be more efficient algorithmically.

An equi-join is a join with an `=` that finds direct matches (i.e. the most common type of join, as opposed to your non-equi-join with a `>`).

If you run-sum the sales column, it is obvious that we now need only a direct match. So joining on `report_date = snapshot_date` would give us a run-sum of `27` for the `2017-01-03`.

If you only want the run-sum of all *previous* rows, then you simply subtract the `sales` figure for the matched date - in this case, `13`, giving us the result you want of `27 - 13 = 14`. The same logic applies for `2017-01-06`.

This does of course rest on there being a `snapshot_date` for *every* possible `report_date`, otherwise the join will fail.

I haven't tested this code (and I'm not familiar with Postgres specifically), but you get the gist:

```
SELECT 
    r.report_date
    ,(ts.sales_run_sum - ts.sales) AS sales_prev_run_sum

FROM 
    reports AS r

LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            snapshot_date
            ,sales
            ,SUM(sales) OVER (ORDER BY snapshot_date ASC) AS sales_run_sum

        FROM 
            time_series
    ) AS ts
    ON r.report_date = ts.snapshot_date

ORDER BY 
    r.report_date
```

**EDIT:** Incidentally, if this report is run on a regular basis but only for *new* report dates, and you say you've got millions of rows, what you're best doing is caching the sum of the sales each time the report is run, then on the next run select only the rows from `time_series` that are newer than the last cached value, and then adding the cached value as an offset to the run-sum you do over the new `time_series` values. That's the basic approach when you're dealing with high-volume data, where you need a running balance, and there are appropriate indexes on the dates.

**EDIT 2:** Based on your comments below. Why are there "millions of rows" in these two tables then? It seems a bit extreme for data of this nature.

Either way, if you can't guarantee that there is always at least one row per day in the snapshot table, then maybe consider left-joining from a date table, to ensure that there is always at least one row per day, or even physically inserting dummy rows into `time_series` (with a zero `sales` figure) to fill the gaps.

If neither of those are acceptable, then it's inevitable that you're going to have to implement an inequality join in the fashion you did originally.

But still consider the other aspect of my solution, of caching the results of previous sums. This allows you to introduce a where-clause onto `time_series` before you join onto it (based on selecting only the rows in `time_series` since the last cached value was created), which will dramatically reduce the number of rows that need to be joined and summed on each run of your query. That's likely to be the only performant solution once you're into the realm of millions of rows having to be joined onto millions of rows.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a snapshot date for every report date. I only have snapshot dates for when there are state changes - the limited data I provided in my example is simplified.

Comment: There are millions of rows because the reports are broken out by client, and we have thousands of clients, and it's actually not sales data but transactions data, so there are many, many rows over a period of 20 years. I referenced sales data because it seems to be the "hello world" equivalent for RDBMS-type questions. Anyways, I'm concerned that left joining onto a date table might dramatically increase the number of rows (since the snapshot dates are actually somewhat sparse)

Comment: I was hoping for some sort built-in Postgres window function for handling these sorts of inequality joins efficiently, but I've upvoted your answer since it seems to be the best (only) option so far

Comment: @user554481, don't forget to mark as answered! If you *are* dealing with financial data, follow the standard accounting pattern I've described - produce periodic summary balances, and then carry these balances forward into the next period being considered. Also, cluster index account data on client number then date. Once you have the summary balances of appropriate resolution (say 3 monthly), your report for a running balance on any particular date will be lightning fast, since you only have to get the summary balance first, plus the transactions between the last summary and the report date.